# What that mean? Some db for Prometheus remote storage have no read adapter

Tags: prometheus, monitor, opentsdb

I am investigating the remote storage DB of Prometheus. From the Prometheus official website, 
I see that some remote storage DB does not have a read adapter,eg OpenTSDB. What do that mean? 
and what scenarios are these unread DB used in?

Comment: here
https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storageAppOptics: write
Azure Data Explorer: read and write
Chronix: write
Cortex: read and write
CrateDB: read and write
Elasticsearch: write

Answer (score 1):

E.g. you could use your remote storage like Graphite to hold your data and display it in Grafana with it, without querying prometheus itself.

Also you could use some other DB as remote storage with better data analizing tools.

Prometheus is good for data collection, but for other tasks, there are other tools worth to try.